# win32gui of mouse control, im want drag but dont

Tags: winapi, win32gui

[not well english, sorry;]

1. i m want mouse drag
2. if delete in source code 'win32gui.SendMessage(hwndcontrol, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 1, lparam2)' = works well(drag - move = click, click to well work)
3. why not drag? and What should I do?

   ```
            def drag_func(x1, y1, x2, y2):
                hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, name)
                hwndcontrol = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, None, "RenderWindow", "TheRender")
                lparam1 = (y1-34) << 16 | x1
                lparam2 = (y2-34) << 16 | x2

                win32gui.SendMessage(hwndcontrol, win32con.WM_SETCURSOR, MK_LBUTTON, lparam1)
                win32gui.SendMessage(hwndcontrol, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, lparam1)
                #time.sleep(0.1)
                win32gui.SendMessage(hwndcontrol, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 1, lparam2)
                #time.sleep(0.1)
                win32gui.SendMessage(hwndcontrol, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 1, lparam2)
   ```

Comment: If you are just trying to move a window around, why not use [`SetWindowPos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) instead? Why do you want to simulate dragging the window?

Comment: The reason this doesn't act like dragging the title bar is that dragging the title bar happens in `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` not `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` !!!  That's assuming you are trying to drag the window to move it.  If not, what are you trying to drag?

Comment: PyautoGui is a great tool, but it requires the program to run foreground.
but, i want background
For - Remy Lebeau

Comment: ????? what Difference WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN - WM_LBUTTONDOWN ??
and what shoud i do?
I making of game
For - Ben Voigt

Comment: I don't want dragging the title bar,
drag in game display

Comment: You might have better luck with `SendInput` for sending mouse messages to a game. The game window has to be in foreground for `SendInput` to work.

Answer (score 1):

I use this as example. but im a noob i "fake" click the widow and send the key stroke i dont even know how to click the mouse with python so osrs sees it

```
import time
import random
from time import sleep
import win32api, win32gui, win32con
 

def drawmouselocation(x,y,posss):
    dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)
    red = win32api.RGB(255, 0, 0)
    for ii in range(10):
        win32gui.SetPixel(dc, x+posss[0], y+posss[1], red)
        for ofsy in range(10):
            for ofsx in range(10):
                win32gui.SetPixel(dc, x+posss[0]+ofsx, y+posss[1]+  ofsy, red)
        time.sleep(0.01)
    


posss = [0,0]
num = 0

def callback(handle, param):
    global num
    global poss
    posss = [580+random.randint(0,10),310+random.randint(0,10)]
    s = win32gui.GetClassName(handle)
    try:
        if num == 0: #edit tis number for the right window
            print(f'Current window: {handle}, {s}')
            rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(handle)
            x = rect[0]
            y = rect[1]
            w = rect[2] - x
            h = rect[3] - y
            print("\tLocation: (%d, %d)" % (x, y))
            print("\t    Size: (%d, %d)" % (w, h))
            
            print("\t   mouse click: (%d, %d)" % (posss[0],posss[1]))
            drawmouselocation(x,y,posss)

            
            tmp = win32api.MAKELONG(posss[0],posss[1])
            
            win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_ACTIVATE, win32con.WA_ACTIVE, 0)
            win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_ACTIVATE, win32con.WA_ACTIVE, 0)
            win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp)
            
            
            time.sleep(0.001)
            
            tmp = win32api.MAKELONG(posss[0]+1,posss[1]+1)
            win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp)
            
            tmp = win32api.MAKELONG(posss[0]+2,posss[1]+2)
            win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE,0,  tmp)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0,  tmp)
            
            time.sleep(0.1)
            
            win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            win32api.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, tmp)
            
            
            win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_ACTIVATE, win32con.WA_ACTIVE, 0)
            win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, int('0x1C0001',0))
            win32gui.SendMessage(handle, win32con.WM_ACTIVATE, win32con.WA_ACTIVE, 0)
            win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_RETURN, int('0xC0000001',0))
            
       
    except Exception:
        print('Exception sending to {handle}, {s}')
    num = num + 1
        
def send_the_keys(handle):
    num = 0
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(handle, callback, 0)
    

def winEnumHandler( hwnd, ctx ):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible( hwnd ):
        winnn = win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd )
        if  "Rune" in winnn:
            print ( hex( hwnd ), winnn)
            window_id = win32gui.FindWindow(None, winnn)
            send_the_keys(window_id)
        if  "Oldchool" in winnn:
            print ( hex( hwnd ), winnn)
            window_id = win32gui.FindWindow(None, winnn)
            send_the_keys(window_id)
            
def pressenter():                   
    win32gui.EnumWindows( winEnumHandler, None )
    
pressenter();
```

using python 3.7 https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0-amd64.exe

and winpy for x64 python 3.7
https://jztkft.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20221/pywin32-221.win-amd64-py3.7.exe